# USB Type C superspeed lanes

Tags: usb

We are designing a device with a USB 3.0 Type C port. It is a pure UFP device, so no role changing.

But I got confused when trying to understand how much logic there is needed. On a lot of reference designs there is shown a data MUX on the superspeed lanes on both sides (host and device), and the data MUX is controlled based on the cable orientation, which can easily be found using the CC pins. 
But is a data MUX always necessary on the device side?
Or can we just connect the device superspeed signals to USB Type C superspeed lanes1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words if your UFP is receptacle based you may need a MUX and if your UFP is plug based (like flash drive) you donot require MUX

Comment: Why is there a difference between receptacle and plug based ?

Comment: Aha, the plug is the UFP, where receptacle can be DFP/UFP...

Comment: If you'r device has a Type C receptacle it could be connected to USB 3.0 Type A port with a A-C cable. Without a MUX there is only 50% chance of plugging that in and getting USB 2.0 instead of 3.0